# What do I need to do in Flash Builder for it to allow me to use flash.Display.MovieClip?

Tags: flash, compiler-construction, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I have a fla I created in CS5.5, and I am trying to use Flash Builder to create and edit Classes for it.  I started out by allowing Flash CS5.5 to launch Builder for me and create the project, and I also deleted that project and created the project from scratch from within FB. The issue I am having is that it doesn't provide code hinting or completion on basic Classes like MovieClip, which makes it pretty worthless.  I've looked at the library path settings, and it looks like the needed swcs are being pointed to, but I'm not really sure what Classes are in what swc, so I don't really know for sure.

I also tried creating a project in FlashDevelop, with similar results. What swcs do I need to point to to make this work (and why isn't this happening by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out the path to Flashplayerglobal.swc that FB was putting in was bad. When I browsed for it, code completion, etc. started working.